# TaskContinuations ran synchronously with async lambdas

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

If we have a a a task, and for that task we create a continuation (via `ContinueWith`), with `TaskContinuationOptions.RunSynchronously`, if the method being executed in `ContinueWith` is the following:

```
static async Task SimpleMethodContinuationAsync(Task antecedentTask, object state)
{
    // some very lightweight, thread-safe synchronous code.
    await Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate async work.
    // continuation of some more very lightweight, thread-safe synchronous code.
}
```

The part after the `await` - will it effectively release the thread that started executing the task continuation? And on which thread will the rest of this continuation resume?

The question is asked when there is no `SynchronizationContext` present for the antecedent task of the continuation above, but I've heard that `SynchronizationContext` does not flow through `ContinueWith` method calls? Is that true?

Comment: "will it effectively release the thread that started executing the task continuation?" - that is contextual, but: invoking the continuation is *inherently* a potential thread-stealing operation, which is why TaskCompletionSource allows you to construct it with TaskCreactionOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously, so that when you use TrySetResult (etc) it doesn't steal your thread; as for `ContinueWith` - the code shown *isn't using `ContinueWith`*, and in general: you should avoid that API

Comment: So you are doing `someTask.ContinueWith(SimpleMethodContinuationAsync)`? Do you `Unwrap` and `await` the `Task<Task>` (the continuation task) returned by this call, or you are letting it live its own life in a fire-and-forget fashion?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, I'm doing exactly that.

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry for any potential confusion around my question - it is indeed simply getting a "hot" task, and adding a `.ContinueWith` call to it.

Comment: @SpiritBob which one? Are you awaiting the continuation, or you are firing-and-forgetting it?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm awaiting the continuation by unwrapping the task and awaiting that.

Comment: Ah, nice. Are you awaiting also independently the antecedent `Task`? I am asking because if you are awaiting only the continuation and not the antecedent task, then it would make more sense to include the code currently inside the `SimpleMethodContinuationAsync` into a composed asynchronous method that would first `await` the antecedent task (possibly in a try-catch block), and then do the extra sync-async-sync work. Pure async-await composition, no `ContinueWith` trickery.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias see my response to Stephen Cleary's answer for more details. I'm aware that I can combine it into one large async method, but it gets messy.

Comment: @SpiritBob it's hard for me to imagine how using the `ContinueWith` with async lambda that returns a nested `Task<Task>` that must be unwrapped, can be less messy than a pure async-await method. On the other hand I haven't seen your code-base, so I shouldn't judge. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you're sensibly right. This seems more of an X Y problem, which I'll sooner or later solve. Thank you for helping me out - Marc Gravell, Stephen Cleary, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I second Marc's comment: [you should avoid `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html); it's a low-level API that has potentially dangerous default behavior.

> The part after the await - will it effectively release the thread that started executing the task continuation?

The `await` will do that, yes.

> And on which thread will the rest of this continuation resume? ... The question is asked when there is no SynchronizationContext present for the antecedent task of the continuation above

Most likely, it would be the thread pool thread that completes the `Task` returned by `Task.Delay`. This is because [`await` uses `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) (note: this is an implementation detail; do not depend on this behavior).

I say "most likely" because [there are situations where `ExecuteSynchronously` doesn't execute synchronously](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/). It's an optimization hint, not a requirement. This also applies to the part of your continuation before the `await`: it is *most likely* (not *definitely*) running on the thread that completed the antecedent task.

> but I've heard that SynchronziationContext does not flow through ContinueWith method calls? Is that true?

`ContinueWith` works at the task level. It has some logic for flowing through `TaskScheduler.Current` (which IMO is one aspect that makes this API dangerous), but has no awareness of `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: I feel like learning all the nuances of `ContinueWith` is much harder than learning to simply not use it ever

Comment: @asaf92: I've written a *whole lot* of asynchronous code, and since `await` came out I've used `ContinueWith` maybe a half-dozen times total. And that was all before local methods existed. Now that local methods are part of C#, I'm not sure if I'll ever use `ContinueWith` again.

Comment: @StephenCleary my specific use-case resolves around basically executing 2 tasks in parallel. Yes, it's possible to just make a whole async method and just put the logic inside my `ContinueWith` in there, but then the method itself becomes dangerous, because it will turn into something too general, and potentially be used by other developers for various things, i.e creating such a method would break the architecture of our code-base. When you mentioned `TaskScheduler.Current` - you meant that based on the current Task Scheduler, Sync Context can be flowed, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: On a side-note: I'm curious to learn how local methods helped you deal with code where you had `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @SpiritBob: If you want to asynchronously wait for two concurrent tasks, then use `await Task.WhenAll`; if they need to be on thread pool threads, then use `Task.Run`. `StartNew`/`ContinueWith` will flow the current task scheduler, which usually has nothing to do with the current `SynchronizationContext` (but it *could*). Local methods help because `ContinueWith` is often logically the same as an `async void` method, but I didn't want to spread the logic across multiple methods; local methods keep the logic all in one method.

Comment: That's what I was doing on the continuations of those tasks (by unwrapping the antecedent task) - awaiting them via `Task.WhenAll`, but I realize that this is more of an X Y problem, and I just fixed it - it now works without using those pesky `ContinueWith` method calls.